# как изменить type input у поля django

Tags: django

хочу изменить тип инпута у поля тегов(при создании ноды, создается с помощью кастомной админки), изменить на ввод обычного текста 
 пример: [тег1], [тег2], [тег3] и тд 
покурив доку не нашел вариантов 
может кто знает как?

[image: jo]

Answer (score 1):

В стандартном функционале django (<2.0.0) нет такой возможности. Можете прикрутить [Select2](https://select2.org/) и радоваться

Для django 2+ я не уверен, так как видел в списке изенений поддержку Select2. Можете проверить, заменив виждет поля на select